# Spring boot and camel testing with @SpringBootTest

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-boot-test, spring-camel

I have spring boot app, with spring boot of version 1.5.8 and there `camel 2.20.1`

Simple route :

```
@Component
public class MyRoute extends RouteBuilder {

  public static final String IN = "file://in";

  public static final String OUT = "file://out";

  @Override
  public void configure() throws Exception {
    from(IN).routeId("myId").to(OUT);
  }
}
```

Und simple test :

```
//@SpringBootTest
public class MyRouteTest extends CamelTestSupport {


      @Produce(uri = MyRoute.IN)
      private ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

      @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:file:out")
      private MockEndpoint mockEndpointOut;

      @Override
      public String isMockEndpoints() {
        return "*";
      }

      @Test
      public void simpleTest() throws Exception {
        mockEndpointOut.expectedMessageCount(1);
        producerTemplate.sendBody("Test");
        mockEndpointOut.assertIsSatisfied();
      }

      @Override
      protected RoutesBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        return new MyRoute();
      }

    }
```

When I run this test it runs fine and I get one message and the endpoint is satisfied.
If I add `@SpringBootTest` annotation, the test fails? Why ?
Also without annotation when I run maven clean install it also fails :(

Anyone have any idea what is this annotation does to camel test, or how can I adjust it so that it works?

Thx

Comment: Post the exception/ error/ stacktrace!

Comment: Unfortunaty error is junit assert error , that assert is not satisfied

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is what worked at the end :

```
@RunWith(CamelSpringBootRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@MockEndpoints
public class MyRouteTest2 {

  @Autowired
  private ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

  @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:file:out")
  private MockEndpoint mockCamel;

  @Test
  public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    String body = "Camel";
    mockCamel.expectedMessageCount(1);

    producerTemplate.sendBody("file:in", body);

    mockCamel.assertIsSatisfied();
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why but this does not work for me? Can you please specify how you are testing your class MyRoute in test 2?

Comment: @Sandeep Mandori 
Message is sent to the `file:in` that is defined in the route that you are testing as a from. 
Message is that at the end sent in `mock:file:out` as we can monitor mock enpoint and then `mockCamel.assertIsSatisfied();` will check if the endpoint is satisfield ( message count is 1 )

Answer (score 6):

Try adding the annotation `@RunWith(CamelSpringBootRunner.class)`. According to [docs](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-test-spring/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/test/spring/CamelSpringBootRunner.java):

> An implementation bringing the functionality of `CamelSpringTestSupport` to Spring Boot Test based test cases.  This approach allows developers to implement tests for their Spring Boot based applications/routes using the typical Spring Test conventions for test development.

Also, consider adding `@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)` and `@DisableJmx(true)`. The first one clears the Spring Context after each test method, that will avoid any consequences left from other test in the same test case (like failing a test with apparently no reason).

The later, will disable the JMX since you shouldn't need it on your tests.

The [official docs](http://camel.apache.org/spring-boot.html) has more information about running Apache Camel with Spring Boot. Here a example extract from it:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(CamelSpringBootRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@DisableJmx(true)
public class MyRouteTest extends CamelTestSupport {

    @Autowired
    private CamelContext camelContext;

    @Override
    protected CamelContext createCamelContext() throws Exception {
        return camelContext;
    }

    @EndpointInject(uri = "direct:myEndpoint")
    private ProducerTemplate endpoint;

    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        RouteDefinition definition = context().getRouteDefinitions().get(0);
        definition.adviceWith(context(), new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                onException(Exception.class).maximumRedeliveries(0);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public String isMockEndpointsAndSkip() {
            return "myEndpoint:put*";
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldSucceed() throws Exception {
        assertNotNull(camelContext);
        assertNotNull(endpoint);

        String expectedValue = "expectedValue";
        MockEndpoint mock = getMockEndpoint("mock:myEndpoint:put");
        mock.expectedMessageCount(1);
        mock.allMessages().body().isEqualTo(expectedValue);
        mock.allMessages().header(MY_HEADER).isEqualTo("testHeader");
        endpoint.sendBodyAndHeader("test", MY_HEADER, "testHeader");

        mock.assertIsSatisfied();
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.